# linux netfilter h323 module

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

In my system There is a Polycom HDC7000 video conferencing device and
a VVX1500 ip phone.

Incoming connection:

```
Src:Any - Dst:ExtIP1 - Srv:Any -> DNAT to-destination IntIP7000
Src:Any - Dst:ExtIP2 - Srv:Any -> DNAT to-destination IntIP1500
Src:IntP7000 - Dst:Any - Srv:Any -> SNAT to-source ExtIP1
Src:IntP1500 - Dst:Any - Srv:Any -> SNAT to-source ExtIP2
```

When I have loaded nf_nat_h323 and nf_conntrack_h323, HDX7000 can not
call outside, VVX1500 works correctly. When I have disabled those
modules, HDX7000 works and VVX1500 stops working. Kernel is 3.5.3.

I can enable module for a specifi connection. (see my previous post).
What can be the problem is? What do you suggest me?

Regards,

Comment: Setup gnugk in proxy mode.  Run all your H.323 connections through the gatekeeper.